.Bat replace double Carriage Return and Line Feed with single Carriage Return and Line Feed
I returned to work on my old script and wanted to tackle a minor issue I have. As the title says I would like to replace double Carriage Returns and Line Feeds with single Carriage Returns and Line Feeds in specific txt files to remove empty lines. I want to automate this since it's not needed for every part of the final txt file but only smaller sections.
Here is what I currently do:
(
    ECHO ================================
    ECHO Printers
    WMIC printerconfig get Name
) | More > Printers.txt

The output is always something like this:
================================
Printers
Printer-01

Printer-02

Printer-03
etc. etc.

What I would like to do is to replace those double Carriage Returns and Line Feeds from the text file.
I was thinking of something like:
TYPE Printers.txt | Replace "Carriage Return Line Feed Carriage Return and Line Feed" by "Carriage Return and Line Feed" > Printers2.txt

I probably have the wrong command but to be honest the last time I actively worked on this script was years ago. And before reworking it for PowerShell I would like to work out a few kinks in case I need to use the bat file.

For your case this should work:
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

copy /y NUL Printers.txt >NUL
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('WMIC printerconfig get Name') do (
    SET line=%%i
    SET removedEOL=!line:~0,-1!
    IF "!removedEOL!" NEQ "" (
        ECHO !removedEOL!>>Printers.txt
    )
)

Your file has always CR at the end of the printer name line, followed by an empty line with CRLF. The script skips the empty lines and removes the last char in the printer line - the CR and echo s that into the output file.

I'd just do it like this:
@(  Echo ================================& Echo Printers
    For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
     Printer Get Name /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %%G) 1>"Printers.txt"

Please note that I have not used the Name value(s) from Win32_PrinterConfiguration, as you did, because those values are the same as under Win32_Printer.
